# How to split daily data to 5-minute data and calculate the average values of the other columns in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame 'test1' like below,

```
 test1 <- structure(list(day = c("01/01/2019 00:00:00", "02/01/2019 00:00:00", "03/01/2019 00:00:00", "04/01/2019 00:00:00", "05/01/2019 00:00:00", "06/01/2019 00:00:00", "07/01/2019 00:00:00", "08/01/2019 00:00:00","09/01/2019 00:00:00", "10/01/2019 00:00:00"), Rain = c(0, 0.2, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SWC_11 = c(51, 51.5, 51.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), SWC_12 = c(60, 60.3, 60.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), SWC_13 = c(63, 63.4, 63.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), SWC_14 = c(60, 60.8, 60.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
SWC_21 = c(64, 64.4, 64.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to split the 'day' column to 5 minutes column while the other columns calculate the average data then.
I tried

```
test1$day <- as.POSIXct(test1$day, format="%d/%m/%Y ") 

fill_1<-split(test1, cut.POSIXt(test1$day, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",breaks = "5 min")) #this code helped to break day column into 5 minutes column, but not other columns and 'fill_1' is not a dataframe, so I tried the next step.
fill_2<-as.data.frame(split(test1, cut.POSIXt(test1$day, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",breaks = "5 min"))) # here it doesn't work
```

I want to convert fill_1 into a data frame, and also calculate the average values of the other columns. The warning message is below,

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Comment: Can you show first few rows of your expected output so that it is clear what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

The format is not `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.  It would be `%m/%d/%Y` or `%d/%m/%Y` (not clear from the data showed) followed by the time component.

```
lst1 <- split(test1, droplevels(cut(as.POSIXct(test1$day, 
               format="%m/%d/%Y %T"),breaks = "5 min")))
```

Comment: I think that's not my point. And I also revised the question as well, hope then it's much easier to be understood.

Comment: fill_1<-as.data.frame(split(test1, cut.POSIXt(test1$day, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",breaks = "5 min")))  # here it doesn't work, and I also want to calculate the average values of the other columns and change 'fill_1' into a new data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you want to put the datetimes into bins of length 5 minutes, and then compute the mean of each variable within each bin?  If so, you should use `floor_date` from the package `lubridate`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

raw <- tibble(datetime = seq(ymd_hms("2019-01-01 00:00:00"), ymd_hms("2019-01-03 0:00:00"), length.out = 500),
              SWC_11 = runif(500, 30, 60),
              SWC_12 = runif(500, 30, 60),
              SWC_13 = runif(500, 30, 60),
              SWC_14 = runif(500, 30, 60),
              SWC_21 = runif(500, 30, 60))

raw %>% 
    mutate(datetime = floor_date(datetime, unit = "5 min")) %>% 
    group_by(datetime) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), mean), .groups = "drop") %>% 
    arrange(datetime)
```

If you want to know which bins have no values, then you can use `complete` and `full_seq` to fill them in.  The unit for `period` seems to be seconds, so I use `5*60`.

```
raw %>% 
    mutate(datetime = floor_date(datetime, unit = "5 min")) %>% 
    group_by(datetime) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), mean), .groups = "drop") %>% 
    complete(datetime = full_seq(datetime, period =5*60)) %>% 
    arrange(datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Coerce day to POSIXct vector: test2 => data.frame
test2 <- transform(test1, day = as.POSIXct(day, format = "%d/%m/%Y %T"))

# Store the date range: dtrange => POSIXct vector
dtrange <- range(test2$day)

# Expand the range of the test2 data.frame: fill_1 => data.frame 
fill_1 <- merge(test2, data.frame(day = seq.POSIXt(dtrange[1], dtrange[2], by = "5 min")),
      all.y = TRUE)

# Store a vector of the numeric column indicies: num_vecs => numeric vector
num_vecs <- which(sapply(fill_1, is.numeric))

# Calculate the numeric vectors' and revalue the num_vecs: fill_1 => data.frame
fill_1[,num_vecs] <- colMeans(fill_1[,num_vecs], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Data

```
# Data: test1 => data.frame        
test1 <-
  structure(
    list(
      day = c(
        "01/01/2019 00:00:00",
        "02/01/2019 00:00:00",
        "03/01/2019 00:00:00",
        "04/01/2019 00:00:00",
        "05/01/2019 00:00:00",
        "06/01/2019 00:00:00",
        "07/01/2019 00:00:00",
        "08/01/2019 00:00:00",
        "09/01/2019 00:00:00",
        "10/01/2019 00:00:00"
      ),
      Rain = c(0, 0.2, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      SWC_11 = c(51, 51.5, 51.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      SWC_12 = c(60, 60.3, 60.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      SWC_13 = c(63, 63.4, 63.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      SWC_14 = c(60, 60.8, 60.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
      SWC_21 = c(64, 64.4, 64.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-10L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```